# server: provide security against unauthorized request

Tags: linux, security

I am writing a simple server (Golang/Java) that accepts request from other servers and write it to Kafka cluster. My server resides in my private network (it contains other servers as well). Generally all the communication happens within that network so we have disabled any outside traffic and it is securing our servers till now.

Now i want to expose this particular server to outside (say on some port xxx). There will be some fix client (from AWS, IP not fixed) that will send request to this machine. How can i secure my machine from malicious request?

**update:**

Just to clarify, i want to secure my web server against requests(attack/hack) other then intended i.e. if i receive a request, how will i verify (i want to know different ways to achieve this) if it is coming from trusted server/application?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to secure your server, however with your question, it's not clear what you really want to achieve, ie. secure web server? secure your application resides in your web server? Generally if you're speaking of application level, you can use some kind of request headers like CORS or custom defined one to limit who can access, or implement your strategy to generate a secret from request source, and to validate in your "server". Your question is just too broad to be answered

Comment: @Anzel i have updated my question. I hope that it will be clear now

Comment: in such case, I'd suggest using a hashed common secret as part of your request header, you only need to compare that header value on your server side before rendering (middleware etc.). This is just an example, but there are so many different ways to harden/authenticate your server requests.

Comment: **there are so many different ways to harden/authenticate your server requests** can you give more information or some link that can help. This will be in my companies network so i want to be super cautious about it.

Comment: To be frank, if you're asking help on how to harden your server, it may be wise to get some help from third party or sys admin. We're not in your company and there is only so limited information, we cannot provide concrete or best solution based on your description

Comment: @Anzel i am asking in the context of request authentication. machine level security is already provided by sys admin.

Comment: Even for request authentication there are plenty of ways to do, what you don't seem understand is that with so limited knowledge of your company/stacks it's impossible to give good advice